# MongoDB The dollar ($) prefixed field '$unset' in '$unset' is not valid for storage error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am attempting to update a document using the Node.js driver for MongoDB

I am performing two operations, one which modifies the value of a field and one which deletes the field, the code that I am using is below:

```
db.collection("myCollection").updateOne({_id: "testDocument"}, {val1:"newval",$unset:{val2:""}}, function(err, result){
//Code that logs the error
```

So the error was logged and produce an error code of 52 and the following stack trace:

```
MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$unset' in '$unset' is not valid for storage.
    at Function.MongoError.create (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at toError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:114:22)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1008:67
    at commandCallback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1161:9)
    at Callbacks.emit (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:119:3)
    at messageHandler (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:295:23)
    at Socket.dataHandler (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:285:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
```

What am I doing wrong? I am sure that both fields exist in the document at the time that the command is executed so how can I fix this error? (Yes it is definitely connected to the server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator if you want to modify a field value.

```
db.collection("myCollection").updateOne({ "_id": "testDocument" },
    { 
        "$set": { "val1": "newval" }, 
        "$unset" : { "val2": "" } 
    }, function(err, result){
        // dosomething()
})
```

Comment: I got the same error while *using $set*: `collection.updateMany({ approved: false }, { $set: { status: NumberInt(1), $unset: { approved: '' } } })`. Turns out I had incorrectly nested the braces.